# vertx redeploy arguments not work with exec-maven-plugin

Tags: vert.x, redeploy

I create a project by the Vert.x starter, use command `mvn exec:java` to start.

And when I add the redeploy arguments,

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>io.vertx.core.Launcher</mainClass>
          <arguments>
            <argument>run</argument>
            <argument>--redeploy=src/**/*.java</argument> <!-- just add this line -->
            <argument>${main.verticle}</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

get a error:

```java
java.lang.Exception: classworlds configuration not specified nor found in the classpath
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:397)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

how to make this Vert.x project support auto redeploy?

Comment: Does it work if you move `<argument>--redeploy=src/**/*.java</argument>` to the bottom of the list?

Comment: Yes, the default starter is working well, but I want to enable redeploy feature.

Answer (score 1):

The `exec:java` goal runs the application in the current VM. As a consequence, the `java.class.path` system property is set to the classpath that started Maven.

Unfortunately, this is what the Vert.x redeploy mode uses to determine the classpath of the Vert.x app that it should start as a forked process.
This is why classes are missing and this exception is printed.

As a workaround, you can switch to the `exec:exec` goal and this configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <executable>java</executable>
    <commandlineArgs>-cp %classpath io.vertx.core.Launcher run --redeploy=src/**/*.java --on-redeploy="mvn compile" --launcher-class=io.vertx.core.Launcher ${main.verticle}</commandlineArgs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I filed this issue: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-starter/issues/142

Comment: Hi - do you know if in vert.x 4 is possible to start vertx in redeploy mode? I had the same issue as the OP.

Comment: Your answer works for vert.x 4, however, when I modify a source file (I am using kotlin) the project is refreshed twice.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong. Have you tried the Vert.x Maven Plugin? It supports redeployment